# C# get text between brackets

Tags: c#, regex, picasa

I have string

```
faces=rect64(3f845bcb59418507),8e62398ebda8c1a5;rect64(9eb15e89b6b584c1),d10a8325c557b085
```

I need to get 2 strings containing in rect64('string')

So answer will be array of strings : 3f845bcb59418507, 9eb15e89b6b584c1.

Should I use Regex.Match? and how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

For example:

```
String text = "faces=rect64(3f845bcb59418507),8e62398ebda8c1a5;rect64(9eb15e89b6b584c1),d10a8325c557b085";
Regex re = new Regex(@"rect64\(([a-f0-9]+)\)");
foreach (Match match in re.Matches(text)) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // print the captured group 1
}
```

See a demo: http://ideone.com/Oayuo5

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this regex `@"\(([^)]*)\)"`

Comment: That can be amended with a match group for hex values `[a-f0-9]` or `[a-fA-F0-9]`, assuming the sample text is a complete sample of what is matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String input = "faces=rect64(3f845bcb59418507),8e62398ebda8c1a5;rect64(9eb15e89b6b584c1),d10a8325c557b085";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=rect64\()(\w|\d)+");
string[] matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```